Is $2^\omega$ cantor space is complete?
Let $\omega =\{0,1,2,...\}$
We define the cantor space is the set $2^\omega$ with the following metric:
$$ d(a_n,b_n)=  \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      \frac{1}{m+1} & \mbox{if } m=\min\{k : a_k \neq b_k\} \\
      0 & \mbox{if } \{a_n\} = \{b_n\}  
      \end{array}
\right.$$
I tried to prove that this space is complete.
So I take $\{a_k^{(n)}\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset 2^{\omega} $ is a cauchy sequence. Then
$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N : d(a_k^{(n)},a_k^{(m)}) < \epsilon 
 \text{ } (\forall n,m \ge n_0) $
So for any $ N \in \mathbb N$ if we take $ \epsilon = \frac{1}{N} $ then there is a $n_\epsilon \in \mathbb N $ such that $\forall n,m \ge n_\epsilon,  d(a_k^{(n)},a_k^{(m)}) < \frac{1}{N} $
I see that if we take $ N \to \infty $ then $\frac{1}{N} \to 0 $ So there is an  $n|0\in \mathbb N $ such that  $a_k^{(n)}= a_k^{(n_0)} (\forall n \ge n_0)$
But I am not sure. Is this last idea is true?
If it is true then this sequence convergence to $\{ a_k^{(n_0)} \} $ and the proof is done.

it is even compact

"Let ω={0,1,2,...}" - do the dots go all the way to the largest ordinal or stop short somewhere?

@AnneBauval thank you. I read it. But I have a question about the answer in this link; I tried to prove that the sequence $x_1,x_2,... $ converges to $s$ But I could't. I understood that proof  and I feel that the limit must be $s$ but I can't write it in official form. I have to  find an $N \in mathbb N$ such that for any $n \ge N , d(x_n,s) < \epsilon $ But I don't know how I can choose this $N$. I am a little confuse about the limit of the sequence of sequences :(

@MartinRattigan I recently started learning about these topics so I don't know very much about them. But I think here $\omega = \mathbb N \cup {0}$. Because I see this $\omega$ in some articles about statistical convergence.  Also in some other articles they use $\mathbb N$ instead $\omega$

As first commented by @EvangelopoulosFoivos, $(2^ω,d)$ is even compact, but let us prove only, and directly, that it is complete.
I find your notations confusing. I'd prefer$$"d(\color{red}{a,b})=\begin{cases}\frac1{m+1}&\mbox{if }m=\min\{k:a_k\ne b_k\}\\0& \mbox{if } a=b \end{cases}"$$
and
"I take a Cauchy sequence $(a^{(n)})_{n∈\Bbb N}$ in $2^ω$
($a^{(n)}=(a^{(n)}_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$). Then $$∀ϵ>0\quad∃n_0∈\Bbb N\quad ∀n,m≥n_0\quad d(a^{(n)},a^{(m)})<ϵ".$$
Your attempt can then be clarified, in the same way as in the accepted answer of Is the sequence space on two symbols Compact??. More precisely:
For any $N\in\Bbb N$, let $n_N\in\Bbb N$ be such that
$$\forall m,n\ge n_N\quad d(a^{(n)},a^{(m)})<\frac1N$$
i.e.
$$\forall m,n\ge n_N\quad\forall k<N\quad a^{(n)}_k=a^{(m)}_k.$$
Then, for every $k\in\Bbb N$, the sequence $(a^{(n)}_k)_{n∈\Bbb N}$ is eventually constant. More precisely, applying the previous line to $N=k+1$ and $n=n_N$:
$$\forall m\ge n_{k+1}\quad a^{(m)}_k=u_k:=a^{(n_{k+1})}_k.$$
Now, the sequence $(a^{(n)})_{n∈\Bbb N}$ converges to the element $u:
=(u_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}\in 2^ω$ since
$$\forall K\in\Bbb N\quad\forall m\ge\max(n_2,n_3,\dots,n_K)\quad d(a^{(m)},u)\le\frac1{K+1}.$$

I got it and I studied the proof in this link about the compactness too. it was very useful for me. Thanks a lot
